# Question about velar palatalisation

Tags: phonétique, linguistique

I'm learning about French phonology and I came across this on Wikipedia:

> Velars /k/ and /ɡ/ may become palatalised to [kʲ⁓c] and [ɡʲ⁓ɟ] before
>   /i, e, ɛ/, and more variably before /a/.  Word-final /k/ may also be palatalised to [kʲ]. Velar palatalisation has traditionally been associated with working class, though recent studies suggest it is spreading to more demographics of large French cities.

Can someone give me some example words for this phenomenon? Are there any audio samples that you know of?

Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 2):

> Word-final /k/ may also be palatalised to [kʲ].  Velar palatalisation has traditionally been associated with working class

Sketches by humour legend Coluche may be good places to look at.

See his way of pronouncing "politique" at 00:16 and 00:18 here : https://youtu.be/zSmbM3aa3hs?t=14

Comment: Do they really pronounce it like that or is he exaggerating?

Comment: It can get pretty close to that, although less so in younger generations.